# Platform crashes if F7 (Step Return) used in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I was debugging a new program, which was logging much output that was going by too fast to read.  Suspended program to look at output; it was deep within the logging package, in a native output routine.  Then repeatedly pressed F7 to find out where program was in my code.   F7 caused debugger to return to Logger (Java) output routines.  At some point the following message appeared:

> 'Debug Source Display' has encountered a problem. An internal error has occurred.
>   C:\Softwares\v4.2_sr2_juno_64bit\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\1193\1.cp\lib\linux\x86\libjd-eclipse.so: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x101) on a AMD 64-bit platform

I have done this (F7) sequence hundreds of times before and not seen this error.

Comment: Looks like jd-eclipse is only compatible with 32-bit Eclipse and 32-bit Java.

Comment: I did not install jd-eclipse plugin in eclipse.I am using juno 64-bit. Does installing of jd-eclipse plugin solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Installing JD-eclipse plugin solved this issue. below is the link for installing JD-Eclipse plugin

http://www.coolwebdeveloper.com/2013/04/how-to-add-jd-eclipse-plugin-java-decompiler-to-eclipse-juno/